# Redirection from a specific page for users logged in but not with membership

Tags: plugin-development, functions, theme-development, redirect

I am trying to redirect logged in user but not with a membership, from a specific page to product page. But it is showing error if I land on that page. Let's say join is the page with id 1867. Here is my code:

```
function redirect_member_to_product(){
    if (is_page(1867)){
        if (is_user_logged_in() && !wc_memberships_is_user_active_member('channel-mcgilchrist')){
            template_redirect('/product/channel-mcgilchrist');
            exit;
        }
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_member_to_product');
```

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: So I moved my previous comment to an answer and also, I rolled back your edit because you shouldn't edit your code like that because it invalidated the original question. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine to me, except you made a mistake here:

```php
template_redirect('/product/channel-mcgilchrist');
```

WordPress does not have a function named `template_redirect`, only a [hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_redirect/) with that name.

So you should have used either [`wp_redirect()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/) or [`wp_safe_redirect()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_safe_redirect/) which are valid functions to perform URL/page redirections in WordPress.

```php
wp_safe_redirect( '/product/channel-mcgilchrist' );
```